# Allow user to create tables, but not new databases

Tags: mysql

I am setting up a new MySQL and I want to setup an account which makes the user to create tables, but not create new databases.

How can I setup this for an account in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the privilege to one database you can use:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

The user would then have full access to the database (`CREATE, ALTER, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE`) but none on other databases.